# How to get the current workflow status from within itself?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, workflow2013

I have a workflow that start by setting the workflow status to, let's say, "Awaiting Manager Approval", after the manager has approved and the workflow status is changed to "Awaiting Director Approval", how can I check this new status in a condition to determine which tasks to execute next?

Comment: helped my answer to you?

Answer (score 0):

Workflow Status is inner state of Workflow and cannot be requested from Workflow 2013.
I recommend to create list column called 'Approval Status' which you will fill with the same value and checking the state with this value.

- Create list column
- Set Field in Current Item (Workflow Action)
- If any value equals value (Workflow Action) select: CurrentItem:ApprovalStatus and fill the condition.